# Intensify or increase Saturation of an image

Tags: python, opencv, colors

Coded in Python. I have the following image that I classified with making so only what was found to have its original colour. Is there a way I can intensify the pixels colour (mage the green...greener)?[image]

Goal is this:
[image]

```
img = cv2.imread("/Volumes/EXTERNAL/ClassifierImageSets/Origional_2.png",1)
mask = cv2.imread("/Users/chrisradford/Documents/School/Masters/RA/Classifier/Python/mask.png",0)

result = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask=mask)
```

Comment: Have you tried to change to HSV namespace and increase the S channel?

Comment: @api55 I have but it only effects the background color

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I convert it to HSV colorspace, and increment the S channel value to the max for the values that are "green".

[image]

with this code:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("D:\\testing\\test.png",1)

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
greenMask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (26, 10, 30), (97, 100, 255))

hsv[:,:,1] = greenMask 


back = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)

cv2.imshow('test', back)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If you want, you can put pure green to it like this:

[image]

with this code:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("D:\\testing\\test.png",1)

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
greenMask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (26, 10, 30), (97, 100, 255))

img[greenMask == 255] = (0, 255, 0)

cv2.imshow('test', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It seems that a part of the small thing in the south is also green (or green enough).

I hope this helps you.

Comment: This is great thank. I am confused as to where you actually increment the saturation to max. I believe it is this line but do not understand it: hsv[:,:,1] = greenMask

Comment: that is numpy slicing, it takes all y values, all x values and the second channel. Then I assign the value that has the same coordinates in greenMask. It should be 255 in green parts and 0 in other parts.

Comment: The solution is very nice, but how do you know which values are "green"? Or "red", or "blue"?

Comment: @MikolajBuchwald that is mostly given by the H (hue) values ( channel 0 ) in this case from 26 to 97 which also takes slightly yellow. Note that in opencv 8 bit images H = H/2 (max value is 360 which is bigger than max in 8 bits 255). To know what value to use I will suggest to use a HSV color picker. Note that the hue values represent a degree in a circle so in some cases (close to 0 or 360) you may need 2 ranges to cover the colors wanted